# Что это за ошибка? [Error]RLINK32: Out of memory!

Tags: delphi

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Spin, ScktComp;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ServerSocket1: TServerSocket;
    SpinEdit1: TSpinEdit;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
    procedure ServerSocket1ClientDisconnect(Sender: TObject;
      Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
    procedure ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
      Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ServerSocket1.Port:=SpinEdit1.Value;
  ServerSocket1.Active:=True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ServerSocket1.Active:=False;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var S: string;
begin
  if Key = Chr(13) then
  begin
    Key:=Chr(0);
    S:=Edit1.Text;
    Edit1.Clear;
    ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[0].SendText(S);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('< '+S);
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientDisconnect(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('êëèåíò îòñîåäèíèëñÿ');
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
  var Received: string;
begin
  Received:=Socket.ReceiveText;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('> '+Received);
end;

end.
```

Ошибки вылазит:

> [Error]RLINK32: Out of memory!

Answer (score 1):

И чего непонятно? Процедура `TForm1.Edit1Change` (поле ввода `Edit1`, соответственно) объявлена в форме, но не описана в implementation. Или удалите ее в object inspector'е, или опишите ее. То же самое с `ServerSocket1Accept`

Answer (score 1):

Ошибок несколько - про первую вам уже ответили, *вторая заключается в том, что у вас в следующей процедуре 2 `begin'a` и 1 `end`.*

```
begin <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  if Key = Chr(13) then
  begin <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    Key:=Chr(0);
    S:=Edit1.Text;
    Edit1.Clear;
    ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[0].SendText(S);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('< '+S);
end; <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Answer (score 0):

Удалите из ващего кода вот эти 2 строки

```
   procedure Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
   procedure ServerSocket1Accept(Sender: TObject;Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
```